# Seaglass look and feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I wrote a simple test class to test the features of seaglass look and feel [http://seaglass.googlecode.com/](http://seaglass.googlecode.com)  and I am getting an exception of 'nimbus class not found'.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 


 public class asd {

    private static void createWindow() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

       //Create and set up the window. 
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

       JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("I'm a label in the window",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
       textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); 
       frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

       //Display the window. 
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
               }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
             try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
                createWindow();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



    }
 }
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/NimbusLookAndFeel
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Unknown Source)
at asd.main(asd.java:31)
```

Comment: It looks like you're using Java 1.5 (or before). Nimbus needs 1.6+

Comment: java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Try taking out your UIManager code, and see if you can launch your code with the -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel option. This will let you know if the NimbusLAF is installed on your system

Comment: @ramya, and in case you're using an IDE (that might have its own compiler!), is it set to Java version 1.6 as well?

Comment: @ramya: "getting an exception of 'nimbus class not found'."  A [NoClassDefFoundError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) extends `Error`, not `Exception`.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html

Comment: i got it guys thanks.... thas my editor eclipse had the previous verion of java 1.6u3 so thats the problem thank you once again guys

Answer (score 5):

Nimbus was not included until Java 6 update 10, so anything before that won't see that class at that location.

Quote from: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

> For the Java SE 6 Update 10 release,
>   the Nimbus package is located at
>   com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel.